# Unexpected video transcoding

Tags: webrtc, kurento, transcoding

I'm trying to run the Kurento-player tutorial with my DLink local cameras using the Chrome browser as client.  The DLink cameras provides RTSP with H.264 encoding; so does Chrome as far as I know.

However, in Kurento logs, the transcoding is *always ACTIVE*.

Can anyone please enlighten me how/ what I can do to prevent transcoding?

Thanks in advance.

Kurento debug log:

```
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:897:input_bin_src_caps_probe:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-0> Set input caps: video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)0/1
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:772:kms_agnostic_bin2_link_pad:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-0> Upstream provided caps: ANY
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:781:kms_agnostic_bin2_link_pad:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-0> Downstream wanted caps: video/x-h264, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au; video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au; video/x-h264, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string){ nal, au }; video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string){ nal, au}}
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:727:kms_agnostic_bin2_find_or_create_bin_for_caps:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-0> TRANSCODING ACTIVE for video
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:897:input_bin_src_caps_probe:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-1> Set input caps: audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)8000, channels=(int)1
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:772:kms_agnostic_bin2_link_pad:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-1> Upstream provided caps: ANY
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:781:kms_agnostic_bin2_link_pad:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-1> Downstream wanted caps: audio/x-opus, channels=(int)[ 1, 2 ], channel-mapping-family=(int)0
agnosticbin kmsagnosticbin.c:727:kms_agnostic_bin2_find_or_create_bin_for_caps:<kmsplayerendpoint0_kmsagnosticbin2-1> TRANSCODING ACTIVE for audio
```

The camera SDP (through RTSP) looks like this:

```
v=0
o=- 1514762567410481 1 IN IP4 192.168.1.93
s=RTSP/RTP stream 1 from DCS-2132LB
i=live1.sdp with v2.0
t=0 0
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:RTSP/RTP stream 1 from DCS-2132LB
a=x-qt-text-inf:live1.sdp
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:1500
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001F;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAH5WoFAFuQA==,aM48gA==
a=control:trackID=1
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:64
a=control:trackID=2
```

This is the SDP offer from Chrome browser:

```
v=0
o=- 1991007996973213405 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:<removed>
a=ice-pwd:<removed>
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 76:99:6C:B8:66:55:8A:0A:9D:3A:63:FA:72:47:14:04:D1:27:40:BF:41:86:40:65:8D:01:CD:87:A6:C4:7E:E5
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2
a=fmtp:63 111/111
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 114 115 116 117 118 43
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:<removed>
a=ice-pwd:<removed>
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 76:99:6C:B8:66:55:8A:0A:9D:3A:63:FA:72:47:14:04:D1:27:40:BF:41:86:40:65:8D:01:CD:87:A6:C4:7E:E5
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 profile-id=1
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:35 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli
a=fmtp:35 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:36 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:36 apt=35
a=rtpmap:37 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:37 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:37 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:37 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:37 nack
a=rtcp-fb:37 nack pli
a=fmtp:37 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=f4001f
a=rtpmap:38 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:38 apt=37
a=rtpmap:39 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:39 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:39 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:39 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:39 nack
a=rtcp-fb:39 nack pli
a=fmtp:39 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=f4001f
a=rtpmap:40 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:40 apt=39
a=rtpmap:41 AV1/90000
a=rtcp-fb:41 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:41 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:41 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack pli
a=rtpmap:42 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:42 apt=41
a=rtpmap:114 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:114 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:114 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:114 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack pli
a=fmtp:114 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=rtpmap:115 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:115 apt=114
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:117 apt=116
a=rtpmap:118 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:43 flexfec-03/90000
a=rtcp-fb:43 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:43 transport-cc
a=fmtp:43 repair-window=10000000
```

KMS to browser SDP answer:

```
v=0
o=- 3864735455 3864735455 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=Kurento Media Server
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed:
a=msid-semantic: WMS
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
m=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendonly
a=mid:0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=ssrc:1897521856 cname:user1234@host-1234
a=ice-ufrag:NRxv
a=ice-pwd:kA6CiN86zl6PHJtRn4vUms
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EA:F1:85:E2:85:03:E8:C2:0B:90:B8:B3:7F:90:D4:32:20:AB:FC:F7:26:96:34:E4:C5:7A:B6:62:FD:8B:C5:23
m=video 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 127 125 108 124 123 35 37 39 114
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendonly
a=mid:1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:37 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:39 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:114 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:37 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:37 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:37 nack
a=rtcp-fb:37 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:39 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:39 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:39 nack
a=rtcp-fb:39 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:114 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:114 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack pli
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=fmtp:35 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=fmtp:37 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=f4001f
a=fmtp:39 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=f4001f
a=fmtp:114 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=ssrc:477590716 cname:user1234@host-1234
a=ice-ufrag:NRxv
a=ice-pwd:kA6CiN86zl6PHJtRn4vUms
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EA:F1:85:E2:85:03:E8:C2:0B:90:B8:B3:7F:90:D4:32:20:AB:FC:F7:26:96:34:E4:C5:7A:B6:62:FD:8B:C5:23
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the source was decoded into RAW.

The solution is to useEncodedMedia on the player endpoint:

```
final PlayerEndpoint playerEndpoint = new PlayerEndpoint.Builder(pipeline, videourl).useEncodedMedia().build();
```

This link explained it all: https://www.kurento.org/blog/kurento-webrtc-gateway-ip-cameras